# List of all the event using organiser_list_events which are live only

Tags: eventbrite

I am using organizer_list_events API method to list the event. It is returning the list of all the future events which has status of "Draft" as well as "live", is there a way to filter the list to show only "live" events only using APImethod?

https://www.eventbrite.com/json/organizer_list_events?app_key=myappkey&user_key=myuserkey&keywords=mykeywrd&display=repeat_schedule&id=myid"

Any suggestion would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can pull your events by specific statuses ("Live", "Started", "Ended"), you can't pull a list of events that are only in 'Draft'.

When you pull a full list of events, your draft events will be included -- so you could filter on your side.

Sorry for the inconvenience, I'll definitely add this use-case to our product request queue.

Answer (score 0):

Though I know that it is quite possible to segregate the list based of the status of the events, once we have a list pulled up using the API method.

It would have been great functionality to have a parameters during the API method call to have a status also. This would make the work of API functionality more easier.

Thanks